# Is there a server Python 3 websocket module?

Tags: python-3.x, websocket

I spend a few days trying to implement a simple server to exchange messages with a browser but it doesn't work(the browser is supposed to be the GUI for my python program).

I looked around and couldn't find any already built module I can use. Either are the modules for Python 2 or else they are too complex. I want a single .py file which I can use to read and send websocket messages with/to the browser.

Does something like that exist?

Comment: I ended up doing my own project: https://github.com/Pithikos/python-websockets-server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might not meet your simplicity measure, but the [websocket.py file](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify/blob/master/websockify/websocket.py) inside [websockify](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify) supports python 2.x and 3.x in the same code-base.

The [echo example](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify/blob/master/tests/echo.py) that uses it is pretty simple.

Comment: I tried it and it seems great(simple.html+echo.py). However I can't figure out how to send a single message to the client :S

Comment: self.send_frames takes a list of buffers to send as messages. You can just send a list of one item to send a single message: `self.send_frames(["hello there new client"])`

Answer (score 6):

It turns out there's a `3.3+`  websockets using `asyncio` found [here](https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets)