# Is it possible to use websockets in Flask and Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, flask, socket.io

I see that [Flask-SocketIO](http://flask-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) only supports Python 2.x for now. Is there a way of using WebSockets (ideally within Flask) on Python3?

Comment: Arguably duplicative of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429695/is-there-a-server-python-3-websocket-module; the key difference is Paul is trying to do this within Flask whereas all of the answers for the question above are separate modules... would suggest Paul look at them anyways as a starting point if someone doesn't provide something better

Comment: Looks like this is what your looking for https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets

Answer (score 6):

Now you can. Miguel's [FlaskIO](http://flask-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) extension supports Python 3 since 1.0 as announced on his [blog](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-websockets-with-flask-and-gevent). Make sure to check [PyPI](https://warehouse.python.org/project/Flask-SocketIO/) in order to install one of the recent versions. At the time of writing, the last release is:

```
pip install flask-socketio==1.2
```